# Splitting JQuery off of a concatenated javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Currently I concatenate my javascript into one file on build (all.js)  For performance reasons and to reduce bandwidth, I am attempting to use jQuery.js from the google api.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js

After doing this, all of my Ajax functionality has ceased to work giving the error:

"Uncaught reference error: Ajax is not defined."

Previously, jquery was the first file to be in "all.js"
I am including javascript files in this order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/all.js"></script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been scratching my head at this one for hours.

Line causing problem:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: queryUrl,
    //cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        onAjaxCallSuccess(input, queryUrl, jQuery.trim(html));
    }
});
```

For the record, I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, jqueryUI 1.8.6 and mootools 1.4.1

Comment: The symbol "Ajax" by itself (no "$", no "jQuery.") doesn't seem like a jQuery problem.

Comment: Im asuming your probably getting a race conflict where your all.js file is loading before your jquery. Mabey try putting your ajax on document load or referencing a local jquery library.

Comment: I made a copy of the google api to /js/ and referenced it locally before all.js.   Still no luck :(

Checking with firebug it is loading both ways.  I would assume they load sequentially.

Comment: @DominicGreen `all.js` may finish downloading first, but that doesn't mean it gets *run* before `jquery.js`

Comment: True @MattKlooster do you have an example url we can look at

Comment: Post the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is some kind of name collision in jquery.js and your all.js.  You should mention exactly what the state of things was when it worked.  Also, what kind of stuff is in your all.js?

Comment: The working version with jquery in all.js is at:
http://www.thompsoncigar.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems were caused by a conflict with mooTools.  Refactored my AJAX to use jquery exclusively, now everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, all worked fine when you had jQuery and all the other code in same file. But now, you have moved all the other code in a single file `all.js` and load jQuery from a CDN instead.

But I can't find any use of [jQuery document ready callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in your code, so make sure to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    //run your code here
});
```

Comment: By that do you mean I should surround all of the js with 
$(document).ready(function(){
//all.js contents here.
}??
?

Comment: not everything, put your applications entry point, the functions you call at start up - like load the first data and so on

Comment: I'll give it a shot after lunch, I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: This threw my code into an infinite loop :(.  I haven't figured out why yet.  Also, the functions I use for building the page layout are not available.

Comment: However, my search box now works.. (the one causing the Ajax error)  So I think this is the right track.